# Elascticsearch error while Searching for percolation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I use elasticsearch for percolation. And i find some error in log file:

> Elascticsearch error IllegalArgumentException[Less than 2 subSpans.size():1]

```
[2016-08-04 10:24:53,673][DEBUG][action.percolate         ] [test_node01] [liza_index][0], node[Qp9QPap1Tb6Q-wSd58ncYA], [P], v[10], s[STARTED], a[id=KaTXb5JUTV
O99cxcvRlJBg]: failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.PercolateRequest@7137f122]
RemoteTransportException[[test_node01][192.168.69.142:9300][indices:data/read/percolate[s]]]; nested: PercolateException[failed to percolate]; nested: Percolate
Exception[failed to execute]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Less than 2 subSpans.size():1];
Caused by: PercolateException[failed to percolate]; nested: PercolateException[failed to execute]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Less than 2 subSpans.size():
1];
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:181)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:56)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBroadcastAction.java:282)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.broadcast.TransportBroadcastAction$ShardTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportBroadcastAction.java:278)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: PercolateException[failed to execute]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Less than 2 subSpans.size():1];
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService$4.doPercolate(PercolatorService.java:583)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService.percolate(PercolatorService.java:254)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.percolate.TransportPercolateAction.shardOperation(TransportPercolateAction.java:178)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Less than 2 subSpans.size():1
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.ConjunctionSpans.<init>(ConjunctionSpans.java:38)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.NearSpansOrdered.<init>(NearSpansOrdered.java:54)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanNearQuery$SpanNearWeight.getSpans(SpanNearQuery.java:232)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanOrQuery$SpanOrWeight.getSpans(SpanOrQuery.java:166)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanWeight.scorer(SpanWeight.java:134)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.spans.SpanWeight.scorer(SpanWeight.java:38)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.LRUQueryCache$CachingWrapperWeight.scorer(LRUQueryCache.java:628)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.Lucene.exists(Lucene.java:248)
        at org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorService$4.doPercolate(PercolatorService.java:571)
        ... 11 more
```

Does it mean, i have a broken stored query or a broken sended text?

Comment: Can you show the query that should match and the document you're percolating?

Comment: If i would only know this. But i have about 100 queries and 4 texts per second.

Comment: Sounds related to the recent issue [LUCENE-7231](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7231). Which version of ES are your running?

Comment: A m using 2.3.3 and it seems that error is dissapeared.
I think it was caused by wrong term query.